# What could Microsoft do, if someone uses their software with violating the terms of uses

Tags: united-states, copyright, washington

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930170/can-you-run-sql-server-developer-edition-on-a-live-production-windows-server

In this question,

What could Microsoft do with taking legal actions if a person or a company uses SQL Server Developer Edition in production environment for commercial purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### They can seek an injunction, damages, or an accounting of profits

**Injunction**

An injunction is a court order to stop (or start) doing something. In a copyright case it’s an order to stop using the violated copyright.

It is not mutually exclusive with the other two.

**Damages**

Microsoft can seek damages for their losses.

At its simplest, they would be entitled to the licence fee plus interest for the period of the violation. However, if they can prove that the violation was intentional, deliberate and in full knowledge of the law, they might be entitled to punitive damages as well.

In some countries, including the United States, damages can be assessed under a statutory scheme where the judge sets a dollar amount within a prescribed range for each violation. For the type of breach you describe this isn’t worth it because there’s only one copy made, but for music distribution breaches, say, this is the way to go.

This is mutually exclusive with …

**Accounting of profits**

Microsoft get all the profit the violator earned. So, for example, if they used it to power a website that generated $2 million in revenue with operating costs of $1 million, Microsoft gets the $1 million profit.

Comment: In addition to an injunction against the violator, they can also seek injunctions against contributing third parties, e.g., an order for the ISP hosting the site to take it down. That's likely a lot faster and more likely to get results than leaning on the violator themselves.

Comment: What would happen if they had also used another company's product in violation of the terms of service, and that company also sued for accounting of profits? Does the defendant now have to pay $2,000,000, or do Microsoft and the other plaintiff each get $500,000?